# Configure DNS server to return same IP for all domains

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, wildcard

I would like to configure a nameserver that will return the same IP address ("A" record) for any arbitrary host name. For example:

- example.com
- subdomain.example.com
- someotherdomain.com
- anyotherdomain.co.uk

should all return the same IP address. Is there a way to do this with BIND? Or is there an alternative to BIND that can do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With BIND, you need a fake root zone to do this. In `named.conf`, put the following:

```
zone "." {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.fakeroot";
};
```

Then, in that `db.fakeroot` file, you will need something like the following:

```
@ IN SOA ns.domain.com. hostmaster.domain.com. ( 1 3h 1h 1w 1d )
  IN NS <ip>
* IN A <ip>
```

With that configuration, BIND will return the same IP address for all `A` queries.

Comment: Works fine, but the main domain doesn't get resolved ? Any ideeas ? eg : testdomain.com

Comment: This works pretty darned well.  The only issue is NS record queries for the domain might explode - namely that it serves the NS records for the `.` zone, which won't respond for any given domain's NS queries.  (But it otherwise works to serve the proper A record)

Comment: any way for microsoft DNS server?

Answer (score 10):

According to the [dnsmasq man page](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html)

```
address=/#/1.2.3.4
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks! That was so simple. Dnsmasq is definitely easier to configure than BIND.

Comment: Do you know if there's also a way to use a wildcard with MX records in dnsmasq?

Comment: It looks like `mx-host` and `mx-target` will do this.

Comment: Do you know how? The use of wildcards with `mx-host` and `mx-target` is not documented in the man page and I can't get it to work. I've tried using similar notation to the `address` option(`#` sign). I've been able to get wildcards working with both `A` and `MX` using BIND using Oliver's suggestion, but I'd actually prefer to use dnsmasq. Thanks!

Comment: dnsmasq is more of a recursive nameserver than an authoritative one (could be used parly like that, but clearly not its main goal)

Comment: This answer was absolutely perfect for my use case :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do wildcard matching in bind.

```
*.example.com.        IN      A       192.0.2.45
```

This has to be defined in your named configuration file for the domain. Just be carefull if you need to define other `A` records for the domain.

Comment: What part of "all domains" did you miss?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the tool **[fakedns](https://github.com/pathes/fakedns)**. The usage is very simple - it will bind to post 53 UDP and serve the **same IP to all A queries**. You provide the IP address as a command line parameter. By far the easiest solution. Requires Python to run.