# With bind, is it possible to define one particular A record for any domain?

Tags: bind

I want to publish the auto-discovery wpad record for any domain the client is in, without having to declare those domains in my DNS server.

Is it possible to define a record for any domain. Such that these requests will all return the same IP:

- wpad.guest.local
- wpad.
- wpad.local
- wpad.google.com
- wpad.myenterprise.ad.domain.com

What I do today is I define a default record like in [Configure DNS server to return same IP for all domains](https://serverfault.com/questions/396958/configure-dns-server-to-return-same-ip-for-all-domains/397011#397011).

Comment: Don't use your "normal" bind for this, set up [dnsmasq like this](http://serverfault.com/a/396966/9461)

Comment: This seems to be configuration of dnsmasq to answer the same IP address to any query, not to any query of the form "wpad.*". Is there a syntax to achieve that with dnsmasq?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **$include** directive on all your domains.

**wpad.inc**:

```
wpad  IN  A    MYIPV4
wpad  IN  AAAA MYIPV6
```

And in all your zones:

```
$INCLUCE wpad.inc
```

Comment: By "any", I meant all possible domain names, not just ours. This is a network that will be used by guests and we can't know what is the domain name set on their devices. Otherwise, this seems a good answer.

Comment: In that case you want to build a liar DNS. It is not a good practice to make DNS servers lie: if you have no authority on a domain... well you have no authority! It can break so many things: mail, SSL connections, DNSSEC, what if google is launching a wpad project?

Comment: In my case, it doesn't matter, really. This fake DNS is used only to get the proxypac file, then all web traffic goes through a proxy that has access to a real DNS. All other traffic is forbidden in this network. I just wanted to have a way to use this provided proxypac without having to do much configuration on the client side, such as: setting a domain name, give a complete url for the proxypac file, etc. Using the "Auto-detect proxy settings for this network" should be enough. I guess I'm stuck with our current solution.